# Метаданные SHOUTcast

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2015, winrt

Как получить метаданныe из аудиопотока радиостанции? Вот до чего я дошёл и дальше не понимаю, что нужно сделать. Или как вариант можно еще сделать MediaStreamSource, который вроде должен читать эти данные сам, но нет на это нормальной документации.
Вот код.

```html
private static async void CreateHttpWebRequest(Uri uri, bool includeMetadata)
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var requestHttp = new HttpRequestMessage()
            {
                RequestUri = uri,
                Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            };
            requestHttp.Headers.Clear();
            requestHttp.Headers.Add("GET" , "HTTP/1.0");
            requestHttp.Headers.Add("icy-metadata", "1");
            var responseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestHttp, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
        }
```

На выходе я получаю:

```html
{icy-pub: 0
Server: Icecast 2.4.0
Cache-Control: no-cache
icy-description: First internet radio station in Belarus
Date: Mon, 29 Aug 2016 17:15:05 GMT
icy-url: http://aplus.fm
icy-name: Radio Aplus.FM
icy-metaint: 16000
icy-genre: World
icy-br: 128, 128
Pragma: no-cache
ice-audio-info: ice-samplerate=44100;ice-bitrate=128;ice-channels=2
}
```

В общем сам и ответил на свой вопрос. Для удобства создал отельный класс и пространство имён.

```html
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.Web.Http;

namespace Shoutcast
{
    public static class ShoutcastMetadata
    {

        public static async Task<string> ExtractTitle(string shoutcastUrl)
        {
            Uri shoutcastUri = new Uri(shoutcastUrl);
            uint shoutcastMaxMetadataSize = 4080; //bytes
            uint shoutcastMetaint = 0;
            string shoutcastTitle = null;
            using (HttpClient shoutcastHttpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                shoutcastHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("icy-metadata", "1");
                using (HttpRequestMessage requestHttp = new HttpRequestMessage() { RequestUri = shoutcastUri, Method = HttpMethod.Get })
                {
                    using (HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await shoutcastHttpClient.SendRequestAsync(requestHttp, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
                    {
                        foreach (var keyValue in responseMessage.Headers)
                        {
                            if (keyValue.Key == "icy-metaint")
                            {
                                shoutcastMetaint = Convert.ToUInt16(keyValue.Value);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (shoutcastMetaint != 0)
                {
                    using (IInputStream shoutcastStream = await shoutcastHttpClient.GetInputStreamAsync(shoutcastUri))
                    {
                        Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer buffer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(shoutcastMetaint + shoutcastMaxMetadataSize);
                        IBuffer shoutcastStreamBuffer = await shoutcastStream.ReadAsync(buffer, buffer.Capacity, InputStreamOptions.None);
                        using (DataReader shoutcastDataReader = DataReader.FromBuffer(shoutcastStreamBuffer))
                        {
                            byte[] shoutcastBytes = new byte[shoutcastStreamBuffer.Capacity];

                            shoutcastDataReader.ReadBytes(shoutcastBytes);

                            uint startPosition = shoutcastMetaint + 1;

                            uint titleLength = Convert.ToUInt16((shoutcastBytes[shoutcastMetaint]) * 16);

                            byte[] metadataBytes = new byte[titleLength];
                            for (uint x = 0; x < titleLength; x++)
                            {
                                metadataBytes[x] = shoutcastBytes[startPosition];
                                startPosition++;
                            }
                            string shoutcastTitleEncoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(metadataBytes, 13, metadataBytes.Length - 14);
                            shoutcastTitle = Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(shoutcastTitleEncoded, @"\0", ""), @";", ""), @"'", "");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return shoutcastTitle;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А что вы еще хотите? На выходе объект ключ:значение, делайте что угодно с ним.
Для воспроизведения потока можно заюзать MediaElement

Comment: MediaElement не поддерживает фонового воспроизведения. Я вместо него BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current использую вместе с фоновым процессом. Но осталось еще понять как именно извлечь название трека и исполнителя из потока.

Comment: Ладно. Я понял, что этим методом я могу найти интервал данных (metaint), между которыми встраиваются метаданные. Тогда еще вопрос. Каким образом мне открыть поток, загрузить, например, 20080 байт данных и уже работать с ними. Не получается через http client. Он присылает только данные заголовков, но мультимедиа не идёт (за заголовками идут нулевые байты и все).